# Calculating Combinations with Repetitions and varying # of Choices

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I want to buy a Sundae, and I get to choose 4 scoops of ice cream.

For the first 2 scoops I can pick from flavors  ${a, b, c, d, e, f}$

For the second 2 scoops I can pick from flavors  $ {b, c, d, e, f} $

How many different Sundaes can I make?

At first glance this seems like a pretty straight forward combinations (order doesn't matter) with repetitions (I can have 4 scoops of the same flavor). But I've tried to fit this problem, and situations that are analogous to it, into all the standard combination formulas but I can't figure out how to make it work, because the number of choices I have changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can distribute $4$ indistinguishable scoops onto $6$ (hopefully!) distinguishable flavours in $\binom{4+6-1}{6-1}=\binom95=126$ different ways. However, that counts $1$ sundae with four scoops of $a$ and $5$ sundaes with three scoops of $a$, and these are precisely the ones you can't make, so you can make $126-1-5=120$ different sundaes.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, this is the same as getting the number of unique combinations of four elements from the set $\{a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,e,e,e,e,f,f,f,f\}$. If my intuition is correct, the answer is the $x^4$ coefficient in:

$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5(1+x+x^2)$

Wolfram alpha tells me this is 120.

You can find a longer (and very friendly) explanation here:

http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56197.html

Here, you can find some Python code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168829/getting-unique-combinations-from-a-non-unique-list-of-items-faster/56961029#56961029